New FedCM Google One Tap stealing focus
Given a page where FedCM GOT is enabled:
The first click that I make on the page is NULL, has no effect, because the only effect is to move the focus on the page rather than the login prompt.
As a customer it might make me think the page is broken, making me leave the site (and potentially lose trust for the future) - assuming that my attention doesn't go straight to that prompt because I don't want to think about logging in.
Is there a way to move focus from FedCM GOT to given element on the page after it appears?
Previous version of GOT was part of DOM api and therefore after it appearing on the page we could easly move focus to the part we want.
Now when FedCM GOT is no longer part DOM we can't move focus using methods like focus() or blur().

I'm dealing with this currently. An option is to turn off the FedCM as there is an optional arg to force it off, but this is just pushing out the problem till it becomes mandatory.
My primary concern is the impact on cookie; we want people to be able to reject our cookies with a single click. Will edit this answer once I've explored a little further.
Websites like booking.com, reddit & stackoverflow all use FedCM and do not focus on GOT. On stackoverflow's frontend code we can see a 'disable_auto_focus' function being called on the credential picker in a module they have for handling FedCM
